# Principal ideals of integers ring of cyclotomic field

Tags: ideals, integers, cyclotomic-fields

Let's consider the $N$-th root $\xi$ of unity and the ring $Z_N$ of the numbers of the form $p + q\xi$ with $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$. I am interested in the ideals of $Z_N$ when $N$ is even and $N \ge 4$. Spelling this out should be redundant with my title, I know, but I am not a specialist at all, coming at this from physics, and I want to make sure I am not misusing the terminology. From hand made scribblings, I am pretty convinced every ideal is principal for $N = 4, 6, 8, 10$. My question is then: what is known for higher values of $N$? I have the feeling that there must be non-principal ideals but what is the smallest value of $N$ for that to happen?

Comment: It is not clear what is your ring $Z_N$. You meant $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\xi)}$ the ring of integers of the cylotomic field ? It is $\mathbb{Z}[\xi]$. See [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field#List_of_class_numbers_of_cyclotomic_fields) for when is it a PID

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had a typo, which I have just corrected.

Comment: If $\xi$ is a primitive N-th root of unity then its minimal polynomial is [$\Phi_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) of degree $\phi(N)$ so that  $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\xi)} = \mathbb{Z}[\xi] = \{\sum_{n=0}^{\phi(N)-1} a_n \xi^n, a_n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

Comment: I had read that page. Oh, I see, if the "class" is 1, then all ideals are principal! So the value I sought is $N=46$ then.

Comment: Yes, the class number is the number of ideal classes of $\mathcal{O}_K$, where $I,\alpha I, \beta I$ are in the same class for any $\alpha,\beta \in K$

Comment: Ok, not to say that I understand everything, but thanks a bunch for putting me in the right direction.

Comment: The minimal polynomial is the most important concept here. For example do you know that $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ ? This is because $x^2+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $i$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension#Structure_of_simple_extensions